# $R \subseteq A \times A$ and $S = \{(X,Y) \in \mathscr P(A) \times \mathscr P(A) \mid \forall x \in X \exists y \in Y(xRy)\}$, answer following

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $R \subseteq A \times A$, $\mathscr P(A)$ is a power set of $A$, and
>
> $$S = \{(X,Y) \in \mathscr P(A) \times \mathscr P(A) \mid \forall x \in X \exists y \in Y(xRy)\}$$
>
> For each part, give either a proof or a counterexample to justify your
> answer.
>
> (a)  If R is reflexive, must S be reflexive?
>
> (b)  If R is symmetric, must S be symmetric?
>
> (c)  if R is transitive, must S be transitive?

My attempt:

$(a)$ Suppose $R$ is reflexive. Consider arbitrary $(X,Y) \in \mathscr P(A) \times \mathscr P(A)$, where $X = Y$. Take arbitrary $x \in X$. Since $X = Y$, we know that $x \in Y$. Since $R$ is reflexive, we know that $(x,x) \in R$, which implies that $(X,X) \in S$. Arbitrary elements were considered, hence $S$ is reflexive.

I think I should metion $(\emptyset, \emptyset)$. Since $(\emptyset, \emptyset) \in \mathscr P(A) \times \mathscr P(A)$ and , technically speaking, condition $\forall x \in X \exists y \in Y(xRy)$ is not (or is it?) violated, hence $(\emptyset, \emptyset)$ must be in $S$ too. But I am not sure whether this reasoning is correct. I would like to hear your thoughts on this.

$(b)$

Suppose $R$ is symmetric. Let

$$A = \{1,2,3,4\}$$
$$R = \{(1,2),(2,1),(3,2),(2,3)\}$$
Consider $(\{1,3\},\{2,4\})$. We see that $(\{1,3\},\{2,4\}) \in S$, but since $(4,1) \notin R$ we have $(\{2,4\},\{1,3\}) \notin S$. Hence $S$ is not symmetric.

$(c)$

Suppose $R$ is transitive. Consider some $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,Z)$ such that both are in $S$. Take arbitrary $x \in X$. There exists some $y \in Y$ such that $(x,y) \in R$. There also exists some $z \in Z$ such that $(y,z) \in R$. We know that that $R$ is transitive, thus $(x,z) \in R$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, we have $(X,Z) \in S$, which implies that $S$ is transitive.

Is it correct?

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) is correct. Regarding the case of the empty set - the condition is not violated. When writing an all formula $\forall x \in A. \phi(x)$ this is an abbreviation of the formula $ \forall x. (x \in A \rightarrow \phi (x) )$. In the case of the empty set the antecedent is always *False* and hence the implication is always *True*.

(b) you're reasoning is almost perfect. You should add not only that $ <4,1> \notin R $ but also that $ <4,3> \notin R$.

(c) Is correct.

Comment: The reason why I decided to omit the fact that $(4,3) \notin R$ is because, I think, knowing that  $(4,1) \notin R$ is enough for us to conclude that $(\{2,4\},\{1,3\}) \notin S$. I just tried to keep things concise. But maybe you are right, I should've included it. Anyways, thanks for the answer!

Comment: It's not enough for the definition of S is that $<B,C> \in S \Leftrightarrow \forall x \in B. \exists y \in C. <x,y> \in R$. Note the exists part. In other words, and logically equivalent - you want to show that $\exists x \in C. \forall y \in B. <x,y> \notin R$.

Comment: Or wait, it is not sufficient. You are actually correct, I **must've** included it.